# Mac brew arangodb delaying start log file path

Tags: macos, homebrew, arangodb

I have installed `arangodb` through `brew`. I am new to both mac and arangodb. Right after installation of arangodb I could start stop it through `brew services`. But since yesterday that didn't work. However `arangod start` worked. Today its taking really long time for the service to start up

```
$ arangod start
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO ArangoDB 3.3.7 [darwin] 64bit, using jemalloc, build , VPack 0.1.30, RocksDB 5.6.0, ICU 58.1, V8 5.7.492.77, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO {authentication} Jwt secret not specified, generating...
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO using storage engine mmfiles
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO {cluster} Starting up with role SINGLE
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO {syscall} file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is unlimited, soft limit is 8192
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO {authentication} Authentication is turned on (system only), authentication for unix sockets is turned on
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO running WAL recovery (1 logfiles)
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO replaying WAL logfile '/Users/neel/start/journals/logfile-17009.db' (1 of 1)
2018-04-30T07:40:32Z [3593] INFO WAL recovery finished successfully
2018-04-30T07:40:33Z [3593] INFO using endpoint 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' for non-encrypted requests
2018-04-30T07:41:33Z [3593] WARNING {v8} giving up waiting for unused V8 context after 60.000000 s
2018-04-30T07:41:43Z [3593] WARNING {v8} giving up waiting for unused V8 context after 60.000000 s
2018-04-30T07:42:34Z [3593] WARNING {v8} giving up waiting for unused V8 context after 60.000000 s
2018-04-30T07:43:05Z [3593] INFO ArangoDB (version 3.3.7 [darwin]) is ready for business. Have fun!
```

I don't know where are the log files. So when I try to start with `brew services start arangodb` I can't check whether it has been started or not as it responds `Successfully started`arangodb`(label: homebrew.mxcl.arangodb)` immediately. So my questions are why its delaying ? and where are the log files ?

Answer (score 0):

The log files are located here: `/usr/local/var/log/arangodb3`

The delay above is caused by lack of available V8 contexts. You can adjust them by setting them in `/usr/local/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`. But the default value there is set to `0`, which means that arangodb is to choose how many are running.

Comment: There is nothing specific in that log. I found `v8-contexts = 0` commented out. What value should I set to that variable ?

Comment: 0 is fine there. It says, that the number of v8 contexts is controlled by the `arangod` process rather than setup to an upper limit. But what you can do is starting `n` v8 contexts at minimum by specifying `v8-contexts-minimum = n`. Try raising that value until the messages go away.